# Oracle Golden Gate to Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, oracle-golden-gate

We are replicating oracle tables to Kafka topics through Oracle Golden Gate. We see that in UPDATE operation some columns are set to null or some columns are missing from Payload.

For e.g. -

```
 {
>     "table":"QASOURCE.TCUSTORD",
>     "op_type":"U",
>     "op_ts":"2015-11-05 18:45:39.000000",
>     "current_ts":"2016-10-05T10:15:51.310002",
>     "pos":"00000000000000004300",
>     "before":{
>         "CUST_CODE":"BILL",
>         "ORDER_DATE":"1995-12-31:15:00:00",
>         "PRODUCT_CODE":"CAR",
>         "ORDER_ID":765,
>         "PRODUCT_PRICE":15000.00,
>         "PRODUCT_AMOUNT":3,
>         "TRANSACTION_ID":100
>     },
>     "after":{
>         "CUST_CODE":"BILL",
>         "ORDER_DATE":"1995-12-31:15:00:00",
>         "PRODUCT_CODE":"CAR",
>         "ORDER_ID":765,
>         "PRODUCT_PRICE":14000.00
>     } }
```

In above example in after image Transaction ID is missing. Does that mean missing columns are set to null.

Is it possible to include all columns in payload irrespective of modifications.

Answer (score 0):

To include all the columns, the extract need to be configured in the parameter file as 'UPDATERECORDFORMAT FULL' , so that the trail files contains all the updated columns. You could check that.

Refer to https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/goldengate/core/19.1/reference/updaterecordformat.html#GUID-9E3E2D2B-2578-4549-8A81-9F0EFBD7DD82